# reference or data on internal hydrogen bond strength

Tags: reference-request, hydrogen-bond

As suggested by the title, I am looking for data on the strength of different internal hydrogen bond configurations. In general, an internal hydrogen bond may form when the donor and acceptor are separated by 3-5 bonds thus forming rings of size 5-7. Below is a picture of the basic examples.
[image: IHB examples]

This is an oversimplification that is most relevant to small molecules (not proteins, etc). I'm sure there are situations where other conformational considerations make internal hydrogen bonds of other lengths possible.

At any rate, I am looking for some quantitative data regarding the strength of internal hydrogen bonds of different path distances. This means the same donor and acceptor atom types separated by varying distances like in the picture above. In general I would like to know how much more stable the path 4 configuration is compared to the path 3 and path 5.

Comment: [Welcome to chemistry.SE!](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) If you had any questions about the policies of our community, please ‎visit [the help center](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help).